# what happens in the memory when i give a global variable a value at runtime in c?

Tags: c, memory

in c Uninitialized static and global variables are on the uninitialized data segement .

so in this code

```
int var; //on the uninitialized  data segement
int main(){
   var = 5; //does this initialized global variable stay on the uninitialized data segement?
return 0;}
```

var is on the uninitialized data segment . what happens if later at runtime i give it a value and define it ?

if the variable later travel somehow to the initliazed data segment then what is the use of bss ?

Comment: var is initilized with 0 as it's a "global" variable.

Comment: Assigning a value to a variable does not change its location in memory. That would break almost all code in existence.

Comment: The program loader allocates memory for the BSS data segment. Most loaders will do that in a lazy manner such that there is no actual memory allocated until a write occurs to the particular memory page that contains the variable. The point of BSS is that it reduces the size of the binary file (on disk).

Comment: 'Uninitialized' refers to its state in the image file.  Once it's in memory (which may be deferred until actually referenced), it will have been logically initialized to the zero value. The distinction ceases to matter at that point.

Comment: so if it is uninitilaized on the image file , what does the Uninitialized data segment contain at run time ?

Comment: At run time it usually starts off as a mapping to a readonly page that contains all zeros. As soon as a write to the page occurs a new writable memory page is allocated by OS and is initialised to all zeroes. So in summary the program always sees the variable initialised to a zero value as required by the C spec.

Answer (score 0):

> in c Uninitialized static and global variables are on the uninitialized data segement .

That may be a correct description of one or more particular C implementations, but "segments" in general and an "uninitialized data segment" in particular are not C-language concepts.

The C semantics are pretty simple: programs behave as if storage is allocated for all file-scope and all static variables before the program begins execution, and remains allocated until the program terminates.  That is, the objects they identify have "static storage duration".  The language does not specify where the storage for these (or any other) objects is, but there is no difference between how objects with static storage duration may be accessed during their lifetimes and how other objects may be accessed during their (shorter) lifetimes.

Whether objects are declared with explicit initializers does not factor in to how objects with static storage duration may be used.  It affects only their initial values.

> var is on the uninitialized data segment . what happens if later at runtime i give it a value and define it ?

Your confusion seems to arise from mixing multiple levels.  An "uninitialized data segment", in the sense you seem to mean it, is a feature of an executable *file* format, such as ELF.  It is largely unrelated to the layout of objects in the program's memory at runtime.  Also, "defining" an identifier is a source-code concept, not a runtime concept. A program can read and write objects' values at run time, but there is nothing it can do to affect whether an identifier is defined.

So the answer is that if you assign a value to an object with static storage duration than that object thereafter holds the assigned value until and unless a different one is assigned to it, regardless of whether it was declared with an explicit initializer.

> if the variable later travel somehow to the initliazed data segment then what is the use of bss ?

Again, BSS and other "segments" are aspects of file formats, not programs' runtime memory.  Nothing special has to happen for non-`const` variables assigned to an ELF BSS segment to receive new values at runtime.  C language semantics provide no way to distinguish such objects or their runtime storage from other objects and their storage.  In particular, assigning a value to an object never causes that object's address to change.

The use of BSS and similar mechanisms is to reduce the *on-disk* size of executable files.  Assigning a variable to BSS establishes its initial value without recording that initial value explicitly in the file.  Generally, a BSS segment will occupy zero space in the executable, so you might describe it as "virtual", but real storage is allocated for BSS contents when the program is loaded into memory for execution.

Comment: so when i launch my program (runtime) there is only stack heap and initilazed data segment ?

Comment: @random, once more, *BSS and other "segments" are aspects of file formats*.  The term "segment" in this sense is not ordinarily used for any part of programs' runtime memory.  There is neither an initialized data segment nor an uninitialized data segment in the program's runtime memory, but there *is* storage for all the program's objects, regardless of lifetime or initialization status.  How you partition and label that memory is of secondary importance, and you will likely encounter variation in how authorities do that.

Comment: ok so where are the global and static variables stored in run time memory in c

Comment: What options do you think there are to choose among, @random?  Memory is memory, at least from a program's perspective.  "Stack" and "heap" are *functional* and labelling distinctions, with somewhat flexible definitions, not physical distinctions.